# High numbers when getting pointer motion xlib

Tags: c, pointers, mousemove, xlib

I am trying to write a program where I need to report the position of every mouse motion. I have called the `XSelectInput()` function with a `PointerMotionMask` mask. Everything seems to work alright but the numbers after printing don't appear after every movement they appear in blocks and also the numbers in `event.xmotion.x` and `event.xmotion.y` are very high, in the hundred thousands.
What is causing these large numbers?
Also is my program getting every number and reporting it immediately or is it being stored in a queue and sent in blocks to the terminal?

Comment: How do you expect us to know, when you're not including any code?

Comment: sorry i didn't realize any was necessary.

Comment: sorry it looks like crap i'll aska again.

Comment: Please read teh [Help Center Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help)